# phpseclib loadKey works on mac, not on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, rsa, phpseclib

I am attempting to load a hardcoded (for the sake of testing) RSA public key in phpseclib (stable version 0.3.10). This code works perfectly correctly when run locally on my Mac and spits back out the key I entered:

```
CONST PUBLIC_KEY = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDYwTO/CJJQ8vbwTRQRWmOS0Pbz
tFCks4RhmPxYANSQV5V9Qy+QSupewn2WAb7zV04r4RqtwxB7stDMbK+uPY+GYR5M
moQuT0YStJ6TXJjiF8i1Y+DBGLnTXOD36y93V8DpuFWMxMYtROskE+Mx1W70+VTZ
EM6k+jvIfzRJoVDqswIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(self::PUBLIC_KEY);
echo $rsa->getPublicKey();
```

However when I push it to an AWS instance running CentOS, the `loadKey` call returns false. I'm not seeing any other error notifications to tell me what went wrong. Any ideas what the issue could be? Some dependency not installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is from having mbstring function overloading enabled on the CentOS server but not locally, which is breaking some of the binary data comparisons. I'll need to find a way around that when performing the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

So normally a private key has the public key embedded within it. So `$rsa->getKey()` returns the private key and `$rsa->getPublicKey()` returns the public key that's embedded within the private key.

In this example you're loading a public key and trying to get the public key. Older versions of phpseclib wouldn't look at the string between the -'s so it'd assume it was a private key without the public key component (hence `$rsa->getPublicKey()` was returning false).

This behavior is different in newer versions of phpseclib. If it sees "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY" it'll assume it's a public key and thus `$rsa->getPublicKey()` will work.

So my guess: you're running an out-of-date version of phpseclib on the CentOS AWS install.

Comment: I made sure to have the same version for phpseclib installed on both environments and still got the same result. I believe the issue is from having mbstring function overloading enabled on the CentOS server but not locally, which is breaking some of the binary data comparisons.